# Edit the alpha of navigation bar when scrolls tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scroll, uinavigationbar

I wanna ask if its possible to change the alpha value of a navigation bar when the user is scrolling a tableview.

I have the algorithm, but i need something help to get changes on real time.

```
  /* This is the offset at the bottom of the scroll view. */
CGFloat totalScroll = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height;

/* This is the current offset. */
CGFloat offset = - scrollView.contentOffset.y;

/* This is the percentage of the current offset / bottom offset. */
CGFloat percentage = offset / totalScroll;

/* When percentage = 0, the alpha should be 1 so we should flip the percentage. */
scrollView.alpha = (1.f - percentage);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's probably too late, but for future reference, you could do something like this:

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     self.navigationController!.navigationBar.alpha = 1 - (self.tableView.contentOffset.y / (self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height));
 }
```

On this delegate you have the values of contentOffset of scrollview or tableView, and you can observe the value of this property to make the behavior you desire.

Hope it helps!